# Function alters variable despite variable not entering the function at all

Tags: python, function, variables

I have the following function:

```
def calculate_cost(distances, all_routes):
    cost = 0
    for k in range(len(all_routes)):    
        all_routes[k].insert(0,0)
        all_routes[k].append(0)

    for k in range(len(all_routes)):
        for i in range(len(all_routes[k])-1):
            pair = (all_routes[k][i], all_routes[k][i+1])
            cost = cost + distances[pair]

    return cost
```

That takes in a dict of and a list of lists. Assume that the starting values are:

```
routes = [[5, 6, 9], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], [1, 4, 8]]
dists = {(0, 5): 83.38465086573187,
         (5, 6): 5.000000000000000,
         (6, 9): 28.28427124746190,
         (9, 0): 97.9081201943945}
```

Now I want to pass these in to my function and return `cost`. To avoid changing `routes` and `dists`, I first assigned new names to them:

```
distances = dist
all_routes = routes 

cost = calculate_cost(distances, all_routes)
print(cost)
```

Cost comes out correct, but running this changes `dist` and `routes` and I don't want that. I've also tried using the `copy()` function but I get the same result. It's weird because `dist` and `routes` actually never enter `calculate_cost`, yet these variables are changed. Can someone explain why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: make a deepcopy of the object where you are doing `distances = dist` (and for `routes`) as well

Comment: what is a deepcopy? I also tried `distances = dist.copy()` but it did not help.

Comment: @Parseval [copy in Python (Deep Copy and Shallow Copy)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/)

Comment: [copy.deepcopy() is for nested objects like `dist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: Ok this worked. I did not know deepcopy() was out there. Thanks a lot. Maybe you can write a quick answer so I can accept it.